# How to find direction and calculate end point of a raycast Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

I am trying to make a gun in Unity that shoots a Raycast with a Line. (in 2d) I am using the player position as the origin and the mouse position as the direction.  This works perfectly when there is a collision detection, but when there is not a collision, I have to find the direction and calculate the end point manually, because I still want the line to render if the player misses their shot. Here is my code to find this end point:

```
        //finding the position of Mouse in worldspace
    Vector3 mousePos = CameraController.mouseToWorld(Input.mousePosition);
    mousePos.z = 0;

    //Calculating whether or not the raycast is a hit
    RaycastHit2D Ray = Physics2D.Raycast(Player.transform.position,mousePos,distance);
    if(Ray.collider != null)
    {
        PassTheHit(Ray, Ray.collider.gameObject.name);

        point = Ray.point;
    }
    else
    {
        //Calculating the farthest point on the line. this does not work.
        point = (transform.position - mousePos).normalized;
        point *= -1 * (distance / 2);
        point.z = 0f;
    }
```

Particularly note the else{} statement.  The calculation to find the point does not work.  It is waaaay too long and does not shoot in the right direction.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either way you are using your [`Physics2D.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html) wrong. It expects a

- Start **position**
- and a **direction**

you are passing in a second **position**.

What you rather want to do is using the **direction**

```
Vector2 mousePos = CameraController.mouseToWorld(Input.mousePosition);

Vector2 direction = ((Vector2)(mousePos - transform.position)).normalized;
```

which then you can use for both things

```
RaycastHit2D Ray = Physics2D.Raycast(Player.transform.position, /*here*/ direction, distance);
if(Ray.collider != null)
{
    PassTheHit(Ray, Ray.collider.gameObject.name);

    point = Ray.point;
}
else
{
    point = transform.position + /*and here*/ direction * distance;
}
```

Sidenote: Avoid to give a `RaycastHit2D` the name `Ray` as there is a type that is called [`Ray`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Ray.html) so it is misleading ;)

Comment: Thanks @derHugo! That worked! :D   There was one issue though, the line went in the opposite direction.  Fixed it by multiplying direction by -1.

Comment: @RylanYancey yeah I saw my mistake and already updated the code ;) Vectors always go `endpoint - startpoint` ;)